# Protecting the folders using SimpleMembership in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am using SimpleMembership Provider in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project.
Why the following code in web.config doesn't protect the content of the folder for unauthorized users?

```
<location path="Content/documents">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> It should work, check if the path is set correctly, maybe you have
> other web configs and the path  is not correct for the most inner one.
>
> What you should also try is to use the asp.net configuration. Click on the project and then from the
> **> menu -> project -> asp.net configuration -> security ->create access
> rules**

. From here you can handle it yourself.

Comment: I want to use SimpleMembership Provider, not the ASP.NET Membership system.